# How do you search on the field "Assigned PO" in JQL?

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to build my own filter in JQL and I want to limit to a particular "Assigned PO".

I've tried to look in the [fields reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-fields-reference-764478339.html) but can't find the syntax for Assigned PO.

It's easy for "Assignee" ... just do Assignee = "Username1", but trying Assigned PO = "Username1", the term Assigned PO is not recognised.

Does anyone know if it is possible to search using this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "Assigned PO" a custom field?

To try searching under the JQL -> Advanced section

> Click Issues
>
> Search for issue Click Edit (If you have a search in progress)
>
> Click Advanced Searching

the field it should autopopulate the choices for you as you type.  It probably needs quotes around the name of the field.

It most likely takes the form of the following:

```
"Assigned PO" = "Some Name"
```

[Search JQL like a boss](http://%20https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/blog/2015/07/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql)

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that I need to wrap fields with spaces in speech marks.